# Execute a PHP script every xy seconds with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a program that is calling a separate php script that is generating google map markers, that need to be placed onto google map. The thing that I would like to do is to place that php include into jquery so that it would get executed every xy seconds.

So basically, how to get this:

```
<?php include('buildmarkers.inc.php') ?>
```

to execute every xy seconds with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` to avoid overlapping issue with `setInterval`
This method will execute `ajax` loop every 3 seconds after `success` or `error` callback

```
var ajaxLoop=function(delay){
  $.ajax({
         url: 'someURL',
         success: function(result){
           //success 
           setTimeout(ajaxLoop, delay);
        },
        error: function(err){
           //error occurred 
           setTimeout(ajaxLoop, delay);
        } 
  });
}

ajaxLoop(3000);  // delay = 3000
```

Comment: Now I have a same question I am getting 500 internal server error when I try to call php file with ajax, while calling it through '<?php include('buildmarkers.inc.php') ?>'  is working without problems. I have tried debugging it with Firebug and Fiddler, but they do not show anything else except 500 Internal Server Error?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 $.ajax({url: "url of php script", success: function(result){
       Do whatver you want to do with output.
    }});
}, 3000);
```

Note 3000 is milliseconds

Comment: What if ajax doesn't return success callback in 3000 milliseconds?

Comment: I did try the specified code and few other variations on setInterval and even one time execution on page load, but I am constantly getting error 500. While I have to note that with '<?php include('buildmarkers.inc.php') ?>' everything works.
Do you have any ideas?